# Using Vagrant and Docker to run Python SSH unittests

Tags: python, docker, vagrant, fabric

How do you configure Vagrant to use Docker as its provider and connect to it with Fabric? I'm trying to run some unittests to validate a server provisioning tool against a raw unmodified image of Ubuntu 18.04. I'm not building a custom image.

My Vagrantfile is:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
    d.image = "ubuntu:18.04"
    d.remains_running = true
  end
end
```

My Python unittest `tests.py` file looks like:

```
import unittest

import vagrant

from fabric.api import settings, run

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_connect_to_server(self):

        v = vagrant.Vagrant('.', quiet_stdout=False, quiet_stderr=False)
        v.up(provider='docker')
        with settings(host_string=v.user_hostname_port(), key_filename=v.keyfile(), disable_known_hosts=True):

            run('echo "hello"')
```

Vagrant appears able to create the Docker instance, but it soon fails before Fabric can connect, with the error:

```
Bringing up machine with provider docker...
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'docker' provider...
==> default: Creating the container...
    default:   Name: ubuntu18_docker_default_1568669393
    default:  Image: ubuntu:18.04
    default: Volume: /path/to/my/project:/vagrant
    default:  
    default: Container created: c5fb82fa523f0774
==> default: Starting container...
==> default: Waiting for container to enter "running" state...
The container started either never left the "stopped" state or
very quickly reverted to the "stopped" state. This is usually
because the container didn't execute a command that kept it running,
and usually indicates a misconfiguration.

If you meant for this container to not remain running, please
set the Docker provider configuration "remains_running" to "false":

  config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
    d.remains_running = false
  end
```

So it seems like the default image is running, but it doesn't stay running. How do I configure Docker to keep the image running and not immediately exit, so I can test SSH commands against it with Fabric?

Edit: Following LinPy's suggestion, modifying my Vagrantfile to:

My Vagrantfile is:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
    d.image = "ubuntu:18.04"
    d.remains_running = true
    d.cmd = ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
  end
end
```

fixes the initial error, but still causes by test to fail with the new error:

```
Bringing up machine with provider docker...
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'docker' provider...
==> default: Creating the container...
    default:   Name: ubuntu18_docker_default_1568754416
    default:  Image: ubuntu:18.04
    default:    Cmd: tail -f /dev/null
    default: Volume: /path/to/my/project:/vagrant
    default:  
    default: Container created: 0e5023317321c5cf
==> default: Starting container...
==> default: Provisioners will not be run since container doesn't support SSH.
v.user_hostname_port(): vagrant@172.17.0.2:22
v.keyfile(): /home/myuser/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
[vagrant@172.17.0.2:22] run: echo "hello"
Keeping VM.
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_dev_setup_ubuntu18 (__main__.Tests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/my/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 478, in connect
    client.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/path/to/my/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 368, in connect
    raise NoValidConnectionsError(errors)
paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError: [Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 on 172.17.0.2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 167, in test_dev_setup_ubuntu18
    run('echo "hello"')
  File "/path/to/my/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 692, in host_prompting_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/my/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 1095, in run
    shell_escape=shell_escape, capture_buffer_size=capture_buffer_size,
  File "/path/to/my/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 935, in _run_command
    channel=default_channel(), command=wrapped_command, pty=pty,
  File "/path/to/my/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fabric/state.py", line 435, in default_channel
    chan = _open_session()
  File "/path/to/my/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fabric/state.py", line 416, in _open_session
    transport = connections[env.host_string].get_transport()
  File "/path/to/my/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 156, in __getitem__
    self.connect(key)
  File "/path/to/my/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 148, in connect
    user, host, port, cache=self, seek_gateway=seek_gateway)
  File "/path/to/my/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 610, in connect
    raise NetworkError(msg, e)
fabric.exceptions.NetworkError: Low level socket error connecting to host 172.17.0.2 on port 22: Unable to connect to port 22 on 172.17.0.2 (tried 1 time)
```

I assume the key message is "Provisioners will not be run since container doesn't support SSH.", but I don't understand this since Ubuntu 18.04 should come with SSHD pre-installed. I tried modifying the cmd to install SSH, with variations of:

```
d.cmd = ["apt", "-yq", "install", "openssh-server", "&&", "/etc/init.d/ssh", "start", "&&", "/bin/bash"]
```

but that had no effect and still returns the same error. Why is Docker reporting the Ubuntu container as not supporting SSH?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
    d.run "test",
       d.image : "ubuntu:18.04",
       cmd: "tail -f /dev/null",

  end
end
```

see [this](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/docker.html#cmd)

**update**

use the following to use `SSH`:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:THEPASSWORDYOUCREATED' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
     d.build_image "/vagrant/app",
        args: "-t myimage"
  end
end

  Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
      config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
       d.run "test",
         d.image : "myimage",
         args: "-p 3333:22"
      end
    end
```

PS: make sure that your `Dockerfile` is in `/vagrant/app`
and your python script should connect to port `3333`

Comment: This seems to be in the right direction. But now I just get the error: `[Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 on 172.17.0.2`.

Comment: Yes because the image you use does not have ssh installed . You need to setup and configure ssh

Answer (score 0):

> encountered the same issue recently:
> for the following example i have give **"nginx_demo"** as the container name.

1. we are using ***Docker as a provider***, not VM as a provider.
   so we can't ssh into the container.
2. there are hacks to run commands in the container

   ```
   $ vagrant docker-run <name> -- <commands>
   ```

   ***for example***: here i am using **nginx image** , now lets get the **nginx** version

   ```
   $ vagrant docker-run nginx_demo -- nginx -v
   ```

   here **nginx_demo** is the name that will be given in the **Vagrantfile**. (name can be anything)

   ```
   d.name = "nginx_demo"
   ```
3. to know other docker commands supported under vagrant:

   ```
   $ vagrant list-commands
   ```
4. to attach to an already running container

   ```
   $ vagrant docker-exec -it nginx_demo -- bash
   ```
5. to get the logs of the docker container

   ```
   $ vagrant docker-logs nginx_demo -f
   ```

to know more with proper example
https://medium.com/@elliot004/vagrant-docker-provider-windows-3350758fc8b3

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has this issue, I created a vagrant-docker-communicator:

https://github.com/ProxiBlue/vagrant-communicator-docker

It does not allow you to run ```vagrant ssh``, to SSH to teh box, since a lot of docker images don;t actually have SSH running as a service.
You can use the prescribed way noted in other answers to use docker to connect to a running instance via bash prompt.

The plugin allows for provisioning to happen on a docker image with no ssh